# Number of levels of a continuous predictor in linear regression

Tags: regression

When designing a study applying simple linear regression, are there advantages/disadvantages for sampling the response to many different levels of a predictor vs. sampling the response to the same number observations when they come from a smaller number of levels? For instance, will there be a difference between sampling the response to a predictor with values {1,2,...,100} vs. the values {1,12,23,...,100}, where each value is repeated 10 times? In both cases, the same range of the predictor will be used.

Answer (score 0):

One advantage of sampling at every level is that you have more ability to look at nonlinearity in the relationship between the DV and the IV.

Another, related, advantage is that, if you sample at only 10 levels, you have to assume that they are representative of the others by interpolating between the levels. That may be reasonable or it may not.

Comment: Thanks! Would there be a case in which there would be an advantage for a "sparse" sampling? For example, assuming that I'm quite certain that I am looking at an DV and IV with a linear relationship, would having multiple observations per IV level make it easier to identify outliers?

Comment: I don't see how.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Peter's answer, I looked this up some more, and found the following:

**The advantage of using many, uniformly spaced, levels of the IV** is that this allows us to observe more directly any non-linearity in the relationship between the IV and DV.

**The advantage of using fewer levels, while maintaining the same number of observations** if we keep the normal error assumptions, is that this will give us less variance in the estimates of the parameters. In the normal error model, the distributions of the intercept and slope are as follows:

$$ \hat \beta_1 \sim N\left(\beta_1,\frac{\sigma^2}{ns^2_x}\right) $$
$$ \hat \beta_0 \sim N\left(\beta_0,\frac{\sigma^2\left(\bar x^2+s^2_x\right)}{ns^2_x}\right) $$
$$ s^2_x = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(x_i-\bar x \right)^2$$

When we keep $n$ constant, concentrating the IV in less levels means enlarging $s^2_x$ and decreaing the variance of the estimators $\hat \beta_0$ and $\hat \beta_1$.